# Live Video Streaming in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, video-streaming

I want to add Live Video streaming (IP Camera set up) in Xamarin Forms. I have found link [click here](https://www.dbbest.com/blog/cross-platform-video-streaming-using-rtsp/) but I don't know how to implement this in Xamarin forms or any other option for implement live video streaming in xamarin forms   anyone, please help me.

Comment: This is way too broad of a question to get an actual response. Stack Overflow is helpful for getting through a specific problem you're facing, not implementing an entire feature into your application. Try it yourself, if and when you come across an issue - then come back to StackOverflow with your specific problem.

Comment: Thanks Jaken for your response. I am new developer, really i don't know what i do. Before post this question, I have google, but i am not getting any solution. I don't want all implement, if you hint me so I will resolve my problem myself.

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp.
It supports playing RTSP out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you likely want to convert the IP camera stream to something else. RTSP is going to be a pain to get working cross platform, and i don't know of any library that handles that nicely for Xamarin. RTSP is also hard to get working well across networks with Firewall, NAT etc.

You can convert the RTSP stream to HLS, and have a much easier time. Conversion to HLS has a number of solutions, from [hacking something together with ffmpeg](https://medium.com/androvideo/convert-rtsp-to-hls-using-ffmpeg-2fe2cdf3a0de) to a more streamlined solution like [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-connect-an-rtsp-encoder-to-wowza-streaming-cloud).

Once the stream is HLS, you should be able to get it working with something like [Xamarin Media Manager](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager) without too much trouble.